# Insert/update data from multiple databases into a master magento database

Tags: database, multistore

There are 3 databases, each with a different structure:

1. Database.nr 1 belonging to a shop. It has one table with products

2 Database.nr 2 belonging to another shop. It has one or more tables with products.

What kind of data is stored ?  id,name,description,price,stoc

Now you have a master magento database where you want all the products from the two shops databases to be introduced and regularly updated.

Whats the best way to go about this ?

I cant use database replication or mirroring, can't use the import/export cause it needs to be automatical and it has to update the master database everytime something changes in one of the other two.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make an observer and put cron job on that from config.xml.
In that observer you have to fetch all product fields from those nr1 and nr2 databases and then add product from that observer programmatically.

you can create two different observer functions an put cron job on those separately in different time.

Comment: This sounds like the right way to do it, but I have no experience with observer functions and cron jobs, is there any tutorial relating to this or something similar ? btw: thank you for your reply